# What column should I create index on?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have a query like this:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 doc.DocumentID 
 FROM Documents doc
 WHERE doc.JurisdictionID = cte.JurisdictionID
   AND doc.DocumentStatusID = cte.DocumentStatusID 
   AND doc.IsCourtOnly = 0
 ORDER BY LastStatusChangedDateTime
```

I've tried to create index on `LastStatusChangedDateTime` while keeping `DocumentID`, `JurisdictionID`, `DocumentStatusID`, `IsCourtOnly` in the `INCLUDE`. However the performance degrades and it takes 5 seconds to retrieve records.

What am I missing here?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Documents](
    [DocumentID] [int] IDENTITY(1000001,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [IGroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ITypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [JudgementTypeID] [smallint] NULL,
    [JurisdictionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [Remarks] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedByAccountID] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID] [int] NULL,
    [InternalNotes] [varchar](1024) NULL,
    [ParentDocumentID] [int] NULL,
    [DocumentStatusID] [tinyint] NULL,
    [FilingNumber] [int] NULL,
    [EfileDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EfiledByUserID] [int] NULL,
    [ACEfileCreditCardID] [int] NULL,
    [ACEfileBankAccountID] [int] NULL,
    [StampData] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [InstrumentID] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [ApprovedBy] [int] NULL,
    [RecordingDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Receipt] [text] NULL,
    [ReceiptNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IsReEfiled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [OldInstrumentID] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [IsChanged] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsUpdatedAfterChanged] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsPaidInCash] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsPaidByCheck] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Consideration] [money] NULL,
    [ExistingDebt] [money] NULL,
    [AssumptionBalance] [money] NULL,
    [NumberOfInstrumentPages] [smallint] NULL,
    [RecordingFee] [money] NULL,
    [AffectsRealEstate] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [FormTypeID] [tinyint] NULL,
    [IsCourtOnly] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Fee] [money] NOT NULL,
    [IsDXRecord] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [MarriageDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ReturnedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IssuedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsManual] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsImportedViaXML] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsAddedViaWS] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Documents] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DocumentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Indexes:

```
/****** Object:  Index [IX_Documents_JurisdictionID_DocumentStatusID_IsCourtOnly]    Script Date: 7/7/2015 7:32:12 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Documents_JurisdictionID_DocumentStatusID_IsCourtOnly] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [JurisdictionID] ASC,
    [DocumentStatusID] ASC,
    [IsCourtOnly] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [DocumentID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_Documents_JurisdictionID_IGroupID]    Script Date: 7/7/2015 7:32:12 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Documents_JurisdictionID_IGroupID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [JurisdictionID] ASC,
    [IGroupID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ITypeID],
    [UserID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Query Plan pics:

http://gyazo.com/395789526c910c973583f9bd9ef11c6f
http://gyazo.com/fa2fcd2ab1ee910db2dbf1f4ff8591d2
http://gyazo.com/55385fd53c459cd0932a1247b9493732
http://gyazo.com/d6a57dcf5f18052c31968152e17bead7
http://gyazo.com/fe21d1112775f29d885a37ec24c12d3a
http://gyazo.com/347d390ea799a4376385bf3de0ca298c

As you can see in the last screenshot Sort is taking 43% I am sorting on `LastStatusChangedDateTime` so I thought of creating index on it but as soon as I create the above subquery which I posted becomes very slow.

SQL Plan Dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6dabmlqpg9y5ol/plan.sqlplan?dl=0

Query:

```
exec sp_executesql N';With cte as (Select *, peta_rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastStatusChangedDateTime desc  ) From  ( Select d.DocumentID, d.Remarks, d.IsDXRecord, EfileDate,
                                                d.IsReEfiled, d.IGroupID, d.ITypeID, d.RecordingDateTime, d.CreatedByAccountID, d.JurisdictionID, Case When d.DocumentStatusID = 9 Then d.RecordingDateTime Else d.LastStatusChangedDateTime End as 
                                                    ModifiedLastStatusChangedDateTime, it.Abbreviation as ITypeAbbreviation, ig.Abbreviation as IGroupAbbreviation,
                                                d.LastStatusChangedDateTime as LastStatusChangedDateTime
                                                ,  d.IDate, d.InstrumentID, d.DocumentStatusID
                                                , u.Username,                                                
                                                d.DocumentDate,
                                                d.OldInstrumentID, d2.Book as Book, d2.Page as Page  From Documents d   
                                Left Join Documents2 d2 On d.DocumentID = d2.DocumentID                          
                                Inner Join ITypes it  on it.ITypeID = d.ITypeID
                                 Inner Join Users u on d.UserID = u.UserID Inner Join IGroupes ig on ig.IGroupID = d.IGroupID  Where 1=1 And ig.IGroupID > 0 And ig.Abbreviation IS NOT NULL   And d.JurisdictionID = @0  )vw ) Select cte.DocumentID, 
                                cte.IsReEfiled, cte.IGroupID, cte.ITypeID, cte.RecordingDateTime, cte.CreatedByAccountID, cte.JurisdictionID,                                 
                                cte.ModifiedLastStatusChangedDateTime, cte.Remarks, cte.IsDXRecord, cte.EfileDate,
                        cte.LastStatusChangedDateTime as LastStatusChangedDateTime
                        ,  cte.IDate, cte.InstrumentID, cte.OldInstrumentID, cte.DocumentStatusID,cte.Username, j.JDAbbreviation, inf.DocumentName,
                       cte.DocumentDate, ds.Abbreviation as DocumentStatusAbbreviation,  ds.Name as DocumentStatusName, cte.Book as Book, cte.Page as Page, 
                       ( SELECT Case When cte.DocumentStatusID = 9 Or cte.DocumentStatusID = 3 Or cte.DocumentStatusID = 6 Or cte.DocumentStatusID = 7 Or cte.DocumentStatusID = 8 Then 0 Else CAST(CASE WHEN cte.DocumentID = (
                                SELECT TOP 1 doc.DocumentID
                                FROM  Documents doc
                                WHERE doc.JurisdictionID = cte.JurisdictionID
                                        AND doc.DocumentStatusID = cte.DocumentStatusID And doc.IsCourtOnly = 0
                                ORDER BY LastStatusChangedDateTime) 
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END  AS BIT) End
                        ) AS CanChangeStatus, cte.ITypeAbbreviation, 
                        cte.IGroupAbbreviation,
                         (Case When (cte.IGroupID = 4 OR cte.IGroupID = 104) Then (Select Top 1 Stuff((Select '' ='' + ShortDescription from DocumentParcels dp where dp.DocumentID = cte.DocumentID FOR XML Path('''')),2,1,'''')) end) as ShortDescription,
                        (Case When (cte.IGroupID = 4 OR cte.IGroupID = 104) Then Upper((Select Stuff( (Select (Case When IsNull(cte.OldInstrumentID,'''') = '''' THEN 
        (Select  '' ,'' + ParcelldentificationNumber From ParcelJurisdictions pj Where pj.DocumentParcelID IN 
            (Select Top 100 PERCENT DocumentParcelID From DocumentParcels dp Where dp.DocumentID = cte.DocumentID Order By DocumentParcelID) 
        Order By ParcelJurisdictionAutoID For XML PATH('''')) Else (Select Top 1 Stuff((Select '' ,'' + TaxMapNumber From TaxMapNums t Where t.DocumentID = cte.DocumentID FOR XML Path('''')),1,1,'''')) End)),1,1,''''))) Else '''' End) as ParcelldentificationNumber,
        Case When (cte.IGroupID = 4 OR cte.IGroupID = 104) Then (Select Top 1 ParcelJurisdictionID From ParcelJurisdictions pj Where pj.DocumentParcelID IN 
    (Select Top 100 PERCENT DocumentParcelID From DocumentParcels dp Where dp.DocumentID = cte.DocumentID Order By DocumentParcelID) Order By ParcelJurisdictionAutoID) Else -1 End as ParcelJurisdictionID,
                        Upper((Select Top 1 Stuff( (Select ''='' + dbo.GetDocumentNameFromParamsWithPartyType(Business, FirstName, MiddleName,  LastName, t.Abbreviation, NameTypeID, pt.Abbreviation, IsGrantor, IsGrantee, dn.GenderID)  From DocumentNames dn
                                Left Join Titles t
                                    on dn.TitleID = t.TitleID               
                                Left Join PartyTypes pt
                                    On pt.PartyTypeID = dn.PartyTypeID
                                Left Join Genders gnd
                                    On gnd.GenderID = dn.GenderID
                                        Where DocumentID = cte.DocumentID
                                            For XML PATH('''')),1,1,''''))) as FlatDocumentName, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE) AS TotalRecords   FROM cte Inner Join IGroupes ig on ig.IGroupID = cte.IGroupID Inner Join ITypes it on it.ITypeID = cte.ITypeID Left Join DocumentStatuses ds On  
                        cte.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID Left Join InstrumentFiles inf On cte.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID 
                    Left Join Jurisdictions j on j.JurisdictionID = cte.JurisdictionID  Where 1=1  And peta_rn>@1 AND peta_rn<=@2 Order by peta_rn',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int',@0=1,@1=0,@2=50
```

It is worth noting that the bottleneck here is the query I posted in the beginning of my question:

```
 ( SELECT Case When cte.DocumentStatusID = 9 Or cte.DocumentStatusID = 3 Or cte.DocumentStatusID = 6 Or cte.DocumentStatusID = 7 Or cte.DocumentStatusID = 8 Then 0 Else CAST(CASE WHEN cte.DocumentID = (
                                SELECT TOP 1 doc.DocumentID
                                FROM  Documents doc
                                WHERE doc.JurisdictionID = cte.JurisdictionID
                                        AND doc.DocumentStatusID = cte.DocumentStatusID And doc.IsCourtOnly = 0
                                ORDER BY LastStatusChangedDateTime) 
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END  AS BIT) End
                        ) AS CanChangeStatus
```

If I change it to `1 As CanChangeStatus` I get the result in 0 seconds. If I create index on `LastStatusChangedDateTime` I get it in 5 seconds and without that index I get in 2 seconds.

The main table of Documents contains approximately 400K records.

Comment: Your query references `cte` which is not defined in the query.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: Correct. That is a CTE (common table expression) I have not posted it in the question.

Comment: Post the exact query, including the CTE. Don't post *pictures* of the execution plan, post the actual execution plan (the `.sqlplan` file).

Comment: @RemusRusanu: Posted as per your instructions. Please let me know if anything else needed.

Comment: Index is not the fix here.  You have a bunch of loop joins.  A CTE is just syntax and is getting evaluated multiple times.

Comment: @Blam: Sorry, what do you mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: You need to streamline the query so it is not looping.   This is not something the query optimizer can optimize ELSE CASE WHEN doc2.DocumentID = ( SELECT TOP 1.  Why are you joining document to itself to get book and page?   Why a left join - DocumentID is in documents or not.  The same DocumentID has multiple Book?  You have page in that table but refer to DocumentID - that has a smell of not being 3NF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a clustered primary key on an INT IDENTITY column. This should be perfectly fine. The clustered key inlcudes all columns and will serve as a lookup key for the other indexes.

As there is a "cte" in your query which is not visible at the moment (???) you should be aware, that CTEs are a great deal with pre-filtering and even to "declare" variables in single-statement-UDFs, but they are weak in joins.

So - quite probably - you earn the lack of performance there...

Maybe you better post the whole statement?

Good luck!

Edit: You wrote that this is a "self-join", maybe you try something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 doc.DocumentID 
 FROM Documents AS doc
 INNER JOIN Documents AS doc2 ON doc.DocumentID=doc2.DocumentID
 WHERE doc.JurisdictionID = doc2.JurisdictionID
   AND doc.DocumentStatusID = doc2.DocumentStatusID 
   AND doc.IsCourtOnly = 0
 ORDER BY doc.LastStatusChangedDateTime
```

Edit: Your sub-select is using the CTE and MUST be slow... Try it like this (for me this is "blind code" - without any warranty :-) :

```
SELECT TOP 1 doc.DocumentID, CanChangeStatus.ChangeStatus 
 FROM Documents AS doc
 INNER JOIN Documents AS doc2 ON doc.DocumentID=doc2.DocumentID
 CROSS APPLY
 (
    SELECT CAST(
           CASE WHEN doc2.DocumentStatusID IN(9,3,6,7,8) THEN 0 
           ELSE CASE WHEN doc2.DocumentID = (
                                SELECT TOP 1 innerdoc.DocumentID
                                FROM  Documents AS innerdoc
                                WHERE innerdoc.JurisdictionID = doc2.JurisdictionID
                                        AND innerdoc.DocumentStatusID = doc2.DocumentStatusID And innerdoc.IsCourtOnly = 0
                                ORDER BY innderdoc.LastStatusChangedDateTime) 
                     THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                END
           END AS BIT) AS ChangeStatus
) AS CanChangeStatus
 WHERE doc.JurisdictionID = doc2.JurisdictionID
   AND doc.DocumentStatusID = doc2.DocumentStatusID 
   AND doc.IsCourtOnly = 0
 ORDER BY doc.LastStatusChangedDateTime
```

Comment: That cannot serve my purpose. I need the bit value 0, 1. Please see my full query and especially CanChangeStatus column.

Comment: One more thing to think of: A CTE is not meant to do row wise calculation in advance. It's perfect for pre-filtering and variable like pre-sets. The calculation per row is better be done in an APPLY

Comment: Thanks Shnugo! That did make some improvement. Now I am down to 1 second. Still need to improve but not sure what else can we do here :(

Comment: Hi Jack, glad to help you! Probably you should completely get rid of the CTE. It's just the wrong place for it. Unless you re-post your statement I cannot answer your question. Please don't forget the upvote :-)

Comment: Sure. Done :) What do you mean by get rid of CTE? How else can I paginate without CTE?

Comment: Use APPLY for row wise calculation. With your clustered PK it is fastest to use joins ONLY. Make sure you use table aliases IN ANY place not to muddle this up :)

Comment: Is there an example link perhaps which you can post? All examples I see use Row_Number() and CTE.

Comment: By Paginate I meant the pagination where I give the column to sort and I give the To and From ex. From 10000 to 100050 and it would only bring those records after ordering by the column.

Comment: The usage of ROW_NUMBER in connection with Modulo might help you: SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY YourOrderColumn) - (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY YourOrderColumn) % 50))/50 AS Pagination

Answer (score 2):

Per my knowledge, you should also create an index on `DocumentStatusID` and `JurisdictionID` in both table since that's the column getting used in JOIN ON condition

```
WHERE doc.JurisdictionID = cte.JurisdictionID
            AND doc.DocumentStatusID = cte.DocumentStatusID
```

Comment: Actually it is a self join to the same Documents table. Do you 2 separate indexes or covering indexes?

Comment: Ok, in that case having index on both column on same table should suffice. See edited answer.

Comment: Do you mean covering index or 2 separate index?

Comment: please think of one thing: nonclustered index never perform as they should if you don't create a clustered (unique clustered would be best) index before!

Comment: @Rahul: That doesn't work. It still takes 2 seconds. I want to create index on LastStatusChangedDateTime too but as soon as I add it becomes 5 seconds else 2 seconds. I want to load inside 500 ms.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a composite clustered index on both the mentioned columns.

Comment: I have a clustered index on DocumentID which is Identity column and created by default. Should I remove that?

Comment: Can you post your table structure.

Comment: @Rahul: Bhaiji added it.

Comment: I see you already have a covering index created on both those mentioned column. One last thing, when you run the query in SSMS you can generate execution plan as well. Can you post that one as well.

Comment: @Rahul: Do you want the XML or photo? It is quiet complex.

Comment: add the pic in your post.

Comment: @Rahul: Bhaiji all screenshot posted. It is very big so had to split.